# PhpPathError: For php72, --php_executable_path must be specified in Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, php-7.2

I'm running google cloud sdk in my local environment (windows 10) and deploy the apps to cloud projects. I can run php55 projects but when I try to run php72 project I get below errors.

```
INFO     2019-10-12 09:22:00,588 devappserver2.py:278] Skipping SDK update check.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 96, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 90, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 600, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 588, in main   dev_server.start(options)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 301, in start
    raise PhpPathError('For php72, --php_executable_path must be specified.')
__main__.PhpPathError: For php72, --php_executable_path must be specified.
```

In app.yaml:

```
runtime: php72
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using `dev_appserver.py` to run your project locally, but according to the Google App Engine [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences), you cannot use `dev_appserver.py` with PHP7.

Specifically it says:

> dev_appserver.py is not supported
>   with the PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3 runtimes. To test your application and
>   run it locally, you must download and install PHP 7.2 or PHP 7.3 and
>   set up a web server.
>
> For example, start the HTTP server by running the following command:
>
> `php -S localhost:8080`
>
> Then, view your application in your web browser
>   at http://localhost:8080.